# Remove Orbitals in FreezeCoreTransformer (qiskit)

Tags: qiskit, vqe, chemistry

In Qiskit's [VQE tutorial](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-applications/vqe-molecules.html), the FreezeCoreTransformer is used and some orbitals are removed. In the particular case of LiH, they remove [-2,-3] orbitals. Why are the orbitals indexed in this way? How can I choose the unoccupied orbitals for other molecules just as NaH or BeH2?

Sincerely,

Maria Gabriela

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A negative index there is just like using a negative list index in Python. -1 means the highest index, -2 the one down from that and so on. In this case since it was wanted to remove the couple of unoccupied orbitals down from the highest one. So that was a convenient way to specify them rather than having to know the total orbitals and compute a 0 based index (which would be valid too). The orbitals removed were known from the molecule itself to play only a very small part in the overall behavior.

As to doing this for others, well you really need to take great care. You can see [plots here for BeH2 orbital reduction](https://github.com/qiskit-community/qiskit-community-tutorials/blob/master/chemistry/beh2_reductions.ipynb), which though done a long time ago, and the code used there is now out of date, are still valid. Freezing the core orbitals is always safe to do though.